# How do you prune with buildah?

Tags: podman, buildah

When I run `buildah containers`, I see this

```
CONTAINER ID  BUILDER  IMAGE ID     IMAGE NAME                       CONTAINER NAME
f5a361407499     *     a24bb4013296 docker.io/library/alpine:latest  alpine-working-container
eb03f2eb1fb6     *     a24bb4013296 docker.io/library/alpine:latest  alpine-working-container-1
bb051587d0f0     *     a24bb4013296 docker.io/library/alpine:latest  alpine-working-container-2
876a6633ccff     *     a24bb4013296 docker.io/library/alpine:latest  alpine-working-container-3
```

How can I prune this list? I'm not using any of these any more. I don't see a `buildah prune` or `buildah container prune`?

When I run `podman container ls` I don't see any containers listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run

```
buildah rm -a
```

To prune all of the containers.

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide a minor addition to the fully correct and accepted answer that you need to run the following to prune these:

```
buildah rm --all
```

As you also wondered about not seeing those in `podman container ls`. You can actually get Podman to show you these containers by including the `--external` flag:

```
podman container list --external
```

The output will then also provide with an additional column telling you which tool owns the containers, so that you can go to that tool, in your case buildah, to prune them.